# SHFileOperation error 87

Tags: c++, winapi, shfileoperation

I am trying to copy the contents of the A drive into folder C:\test\disk1. Folder disk1 already exists. The program compiles but when it runs I get error 87. I know error 87 has something to do with an invalid parameter but Im not sure where the problem lies. Has anyone any ideas?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    const wchar_t *const sourceFile = L"A:\\";
    const wchar_t *const outputFile = L"C:\\test\\disk1";

    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW fileOperation;
    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    fileOperation.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    fileOperation.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR |
                               FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_FILESONLY;
    fileOperation.pFrom = sourceFile;
    fileOperation.pTo = outputFile;

    int result = SHFileOperationW(&fileOperation);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("SHFileOperation Failure: Error%u\n", result);
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note the documentation of [SHFILEOPSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795(v=vs.85).aspx) and in particular that of `pFrom` and `pTo`:

```
  PCZZTSTR     pFrom;
  PCZZTSTR     pTo;
```

What does `PCZZTSTR` mean?

> ```
> pFrom
> Type: PCZZTSTR
> Note  This string must be double-null terminated.
> ```

So your fix is to supply an additional trailing zero.

```
const wchar_t *const sourceFile = L"A:\\\0";
const wchar_t *const outputFile = L"C:\\test\\disk1\0";
```

Note that Windows API functions accept `/` as a directory separator, so that can be written as the slightly easier to read:

```
const wchar_t *const sourceFile = L"A:/\0";
const wchar_t *const outputFile = L"C:/test/disk1\0";
```

(`PCZZSTR` is actually a pointer to a list of zero terminated strings which is terminated by an empty string.)

Comment: The file I/O APIs sometimes translate forward slashes to backslahes, and sometimes they don't. The path separator on Windows is a backslash. Suggesting to use the 'wrong' separator to improve readability is questionable. If this is about readability, you can use `L"A:\\" L"\0"` and `L"C:\\test\\disk1" L"\0"` instead.

Comment: @RobbieJ : That's a separate question.  Please ask it as such.  (And note the tag that IInspectable added.)